Multiple AWS accounts with MacOS Safari and Passwords.app
I need to save and use several passwords for different accounts on AWS. The username is unhelpfully the same for each account. Unfortunately the MacOS Password App keeps adding a generic (regional) signin URL to the Passwords.app on my behalf. Here's what happens:

Go to https://my-co.signin.aws.amazon.com/console
Add or select the username and password from Passwords.app
The browser then redirects to a generic regional page (in my case
https://eu-north-1.signin.aws.amazon.com/console)
Try to login with a different account alias e.g.
https://my-other-co.signin.aws.amazon.com/console
Safari offers the first set of credentials and offers to overwrite
the password.
When I check in Passwords.app for each alias I login with,
eu-north-1 has also been added (without my acknowledgment) as a URL
and will be suggested.

Passwords.app seems to view the redirect page as primary and acts accordingly with the first supplied set of credentials.
So my question is, how do I get Safari/Passwords.app to recognise the different URLs and/or ignore the subsequent redirect?
